# In what sutta does the Buddha talk about Paccekabuddhas?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras, texts, buddhas

Question is in the title.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [MN116](https://suttacentral.net/mn116),

> Once upon a time, five hundred Buddhas awakened for themselves dwelt
> for a long time on this Isigili. They were seen entering the mountain,
> but after entering were seen no more. When people noticed this they
> said: ‘That mountain swallows these hermits!’ That’s how it came to be
> known as Isigili.
>
> *desessāmi, bhikkhave, **paccekabuddhāna**ṁ nāmāni.*
> I shall teach the names of the **Buddhas awakened for themselves**.
>
> *Taṁ suṇātha, sādhukaṁ manasi karotha, bhāsissāmī”ti.* 
> Listen and pay close attention, I will speak.
>
> “Yes, sir,” they replied. The Buddha said this:
>
> “The Buddhas awakened for themselves who dwelt for a long time on this
> Isigili were named Ariṭṭha, Upariṭṭha, Tagarasikhin, Yasassin,
> Sudassana, Piyadassin, Gandhāra, Piṇḍola, Upāsabha, Nītha, Tatha,
> Sutavā, and Bhāvitatta. ......
>
> These and other mighty ones awakened for themselves, enders of the
> attachment to rebirth— honor these great hermits who are fully
> extinguished, having got past all ties, limitless.”

Other translation: [From Piyadassi Thera](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.116.piya.html)

Comment: I'll just update your answer to provide a bit more of the surrounding text to add more context.

Answer (score 2):

From [AN 10.16](https://suttacentral.net/an10.16/en/bodhi):

> “Bhikkhus, these ten persons are worthy of gifts, worthy of
> hospitality, worthy of offerings, worthy of reverential salutation, an
> unsurpassed field of merit for the world. What ten? The Tathāgata, the
> Arahant, the Perfectly Enlightened One; a **paccekabuddha**; the one
> liberated in both respects; the one liberated by wisdom; the body
> witness; the one attained to view; the one liberated by faith; the
> Dhamma follower; the faith follower; and the clan member. These ten
> persons are worthy of gifts, worthy of hospitality, worthy of
> offerings, worthy of reverential salutation, an unsurpassed field of
> merit for the world.”

From [AN 9.20](https://suttacentral.net/an9.20/en/sujato):

> It would be more fruitful to feed one person accomplished in view than
> that great offering of Velāma.
>
> It would be more fruitful to feed one once-returner than a hundred
> persons accomplished in view.
>
> It would be more fruitful to feed one non-returner than a hundred
> once-returners.
>
> It would be more fruitful to feed one perfected one than a hundred
> non-returners.
>
> It would be more fruitful to feed one **Buddha awakened for themselves**
> than a hundred perfected ones.
> *yo ca sataṃ arahantānaṃ bhojeyya, yo cekaṃ **paccekabuddhaṃ** bhojeyya … pe …*
>
> It would be more fruitful to feed one Realized One, a perfected one, a
> fully awakened Buddha than a hundred Buddhas awakened for themselves.

From [Ud 5.3](https://suttacentral.net/ud5.3/en/anandajoti):

> “Formerly, monks, the leper Suppabuddha was a son of a wealthy
> merchant in this very Rājagaha. While going to his pleasure park he
> saw the **Pacceka Buddha** Tagarasikkhī entering the city for alms, and
> having seen him, this occurred to him: “Who is this leper roaming
> around with his leper’s robe?” And having spat, and circumambulated
> him disrespectfully on the left side, he went away.